# Hereditary Discrepancy

Tags: co.combinatorics

It is known that it is NP-hard to distinguish whether a set system has discrepancy $0$ or $O(\sqrt{n})$, given that the set system has $n$ elements and $m=O(n)$ sets.

In general if it is so hopeless to estimate or upper-bound discrepancy , then why do we care about algorithms that give colorings of $O(\mathrm{herdisc}(C)(\log m\log n)^{1/2})$ discrepancy ? I am interested in applications of discrepancy in approximation algorithms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually for applications to approximation algorithms, hereditary discrepancy is often the right quantity. The central result here is due to [Lovasz, Spencer and Vesztergombi](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669886800415):

> **LSV Thm.** For any $m\times n$ matrix $A$ and any vector $x \in [0,1]^n$, there exists a vector $y \in \{0,1\}^n$ such that $\|Ax - Ay\|_\infty \leq \mathrm{herdisc}(A)$.

(If you don't have access to the paper, you can check Lemma 1.14 in [Chazelle's book](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/book.pdf) for a proof.)
This theorem can then be used to round a solution to a linear programming relaxation of a combinatorial problem. A very nice example is the recent work on the bin packing problem: for the basic idea check the paper by [Eisenbrand, Palvoelgyi, and Rothvoss](http://www.math.washington.edu/~rothvoss/publications/BinPackingViaDiscrepancyOfPermutations-talg.pdf), and for the best result to date, check this recent [arxiv paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.08796) by Hoberg and Rothvoss.

The exact guarantee you mention -- efficiently finding a coloring with discrepancy bounded by the hereditary discrepancy -- fits very nicely into this, because it's exactly the guarantee to make the LSV theorem constructive. I.e. if you have an algorithm that for any matrix $A$ finds in polynomial time a coloring $x \in \{-1, 1\}^n$ such that $\|Ax\|_\infty \leq \alpha \cdot \mathrm{herdisc}(A)$, then we have an *efficient LSV theorem* in which for any $A$ and $x$ there exists a *polynomial time computable* $y$ such that $\|Ax - Ay\|_\infty \leq \alpha \cdot \mathrm{herdisc}(A)$.

By the way, hereditary discrepancy turns out to be the right quantity in other applications too: constructing $\epsilon$-samples and differential privacy, for example. Also it can be [efficiently approximated](http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.6204) up to a factor of $\log^{3/2}m$. The [largest hardness of approximation known](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2013/159/) for hereditary discrepancy is factor 2, so hereditary discrepancy may even be approximable within a fixed constant (although I'd be surprised).

**EDIT**: Let me say a few more words about the approximation, since you say you want to find upper bounds on $\mathrm{herdisc}$. Although my paper with Kunal is not written this way, what we show in fact is that 
$$
\gamma_2(A)/O(\log \min(m,n)) \leq \mathrm{herdisc}(A) \leq O(\sqrt{\log m})\gamma_2(A),
$$
where $\gamma_2(A)$ is a classical factorization norm, equal to the smallest number $t$ such that there exist vectors $u_1, \ldots, u_m$, $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ satisfying

1. for all $i,j$, $\|u_i\|^2 \leq t$ and $\|v_j\|^2 \leq t$;
2. for all $i, j$, $a_{i,j} = u_i^T v_j$.

It's not hard to turn this definition into a semidefinite program that computes $\gamma_2(A)$. Besides the approximation, this is very useful because $\gamma_2$ has many nice properties which make it easy to give upper and lower bounds which then translate into upper and lower bounds for hereditary discrepancy. My [paper with Matousek](http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.1376) has some applications.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I happened to read an excellent survey article by Nikhil Bansal which cleared a lot of these doubts. So, is it correct that $herdisc$ is approximable to $\log^{3/2} m$, in the regime where $m = O(n)$ ?. I understand the algorithmic perspective that I can round to intergral solutions such that $||Ax - Ay|| _{\infty} \leq herdisc(A)$. I want to upper-bound $herdisc$ efficiently, so that I can provide error bounds in terms of $m,n$.

Comment: Yes, Nikhil's survey is highly recommended. You can approximate $\mathrm{herdisc}(A)$ up to $\log^{3/2} m$ no matter what $m$ and $n$ are: see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I have a fair idea of what is doable. I will go through the papers you recommended.

Comment: Is this the review by Nikhil that is being referred to, http://www.win.tue.nl/~nikhil/pubs/disc-ismp%20-final.pdf ?

Comment: @Anirbit The article I was referring to is this one : http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-04696-9_6

Comment: "It's not hard to turn this definition into a semidefinite program that computes γ2(A)" Could you explain how to do this?

Comment: It really is a nice exercise, you should try it. If you fail, see  page 9 of http://www.research.rutgers.edu/~troyjlee/dpt.pdf.